# System of infinite equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, systems-of-equations, binomial-coefficients

While working I encountered the following system of equations:

$\binom{0}{0} x_0+\binom{1}{0} x_1+\binom{2}{0} x_2+\binom{3}{0} x_3+...=\alpha x_0$

$\binom{1}{1} x_1+\binom{2}{1} x_2+\binom{3}{1} x_3+...=\alpha x_1$

$\binom{2}{2} x_2+\binom{3}{2} x_3+...=\alpha x_2$

$\binom{3}{3} x_3+...=\alpha x_3$

$\vdots$

where $\alpha$ is a fixed real number. I want to find the values of $x_1,$ $x_2,$ $\ldots$ in terms of $x_0.$ The commonly used substitution method is not working in this case. Binomial coefficient is not allowing us to use the substitution method. Is there anyway to find the values of $x_1,$ $x_2,$ $\ldots$? Please help.

Comment: On the second line, you have a $\binom{3}{2}$ that should be a $\binom{3}{1}$? Right ?

Comment: Also, $x_2$ is twice.

Answer (score 2):

The answer we are going to establish is:

> $$\forall k, \ x_k=x_0\dfrac{1}{2^k} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \alpha=2. \tag{1}$$

In fact, your issue is equivalent to:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&\cdots \\
0&1&2&3&4&\cdots \\
0&0&1&3&6&\cdots \\
0&0&0&1&4&\cdots \\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots
\end{pmatrix}}_P \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}}_X=\alpha \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}}_X\tag{2}$$

expressing that $X$ is an eigenvector of a so-called infinite Pascal matrix associated with eigenvalue $\alpha$.

You will find in this nice [MIT paper](https://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/pascal-work.pdf) by Strang and Edelman a description of the finite and infinite Pascal matrices and some of their properties.

In particular, one finds in this paper the following formula (numbered (12) page 9):

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&\cdots \\
0&1&2&3&4&\cdots \\
0&0&1&3&6&\cdots \\
0&0&0&1&4&\cdots \\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\
x\\
x^2\\
x^3\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1/(1-x) \\
x/(1-x)^2\\
x^2/(1-x)^3\\
x^3/(1-x)^4\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}\tag{3}$$

Let us remark that the different identities in (3) aren't at all mysterious:

- the first entry expresses the sum of a geometric series,
- the second one expresses the derivative of this sum multiplied by $x$ in order to generate a  shift, etc.

Otherwise said:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&\cdots \\
0&1&2&3&4&\cdots \\
0&0&1&3&6&\cdots \\
0&0&0&1&4&\cdots \\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\
x\\
x^2\\
x^3\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{1-x}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\(x/(1-x))\\
(x/(1-x))^2\\
(x/(1-x))^3\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$

If we take $x$ such that

$$1=\dfrac{1}{1-x} \ \iff \ x=\dfrac12$$

(2) expresses the eigenvalues-eigenvector we were waiting for... with

$$x_k=\dfrac{1}{2^k} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \alpha=\dfrac{1}{x}=2.\tag{5}$$

But, as the multiple of an eigenvector is still an eigenvector, we can deduce from (5) the general solution (as a function of $x_0$) as given in (1).

**Remark:** A paradoxical fact takes place here (in fact not so paradoxical...).

If one imagine the infinite matrix in (1) as the limit of successive russian dolls matrices as depicted here:

[image]

These "nested" matrices have in particular all their eigenvalues equal to $1$... associated for example with the all-ones vector. No continuity argument can explain why "suddenly at infinity", eigenvalue $2$ suddenly appears. But in fact the image by $P$ of the "all-ones" infinite vector is indefinite (the vectors have to be in $\ell_2$ to be eligible)... This is typical of difficulties when dealing with infinite matrices.

Let us give another difference between finite and infinite matrices. Consider

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&\cdots \\
0&0&1&0&0&\cdots \\
0&0&0&1&0&\cdots \\
0&0&0&0&1&\cdots \\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots
\end{pmatrix} \ \text{giving} \ AA^T-A^TA=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&\cdots \\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots \\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots \\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots \\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots
\end{pmatrix}$$

As a consequence: $$\operatorname{trace}(AA^T-A^TA)=1$$

which is false for finite dimensional matrices.

Comment: Any comment ... ?

Comment: See the remark I have placed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

@Jean Marie, you have explained this so beautifully. Thank you for refering the paper by Edelman and Strang. I wonder when we consider $q$-binomial coefficient in place of ordinary binomial coefficient will the result will be analogues that is

$x_k=\frac{1}{G_k}x_0$

where $G_k=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}_q$.

Please notice that $G_k=2^k$ when $q\to1$.